# GRE Math Subject Practice Test Question $53$

Tags: calculus, gre-exam

f and g are function of a real variable such that $g(x) = \int_0^x f(y)(y-x)dy$ for all $x$.  If g is three times continuously differentiable, what is the greatest integer n for which f must be $n$ times continuously differentiable.  Apparently the answer is $1$.  Can anyone explain how to do this problem?

Since the derivative of $g$ is $0$, the integral must be constant, but I don't see how to quickly use this to say anything about $f$.

Comment: Surely they assumed $f$ was continuous?

Comment: @zhw. They didn't assume that, they just said that they were functions and that g was 3 times continuously differentiable.

Comment: what if you consider as f the dirichlet function? then g is identically zero but f is not even continuous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we can compute $g'(x),g''(x),g'''(x)$ directly:

$$g'(x)=f(x)x-\int_{0}^{x}f(y)\;dy-xf(x)=-\int_{0}^{x}f(y)\;dy$$

$$g''(x)=-f(x)$$

$$g'''(x)=-f'(x)$$

Comment: Thanks, I see what I did wrong.

Comment: @agha If you allow me to suggest a correction, I would remark that the derivative (w.r.t $x$) of $\int_{0}^{x}f(y)\;dy$  is $f(x)$, NOT $(f(x)-f(0))$.  So your computation should be $g'(x)=f(x)x-\int_{0}^{x}f(y)\;dy-x(f(x))=-\int_{0}^{x}f(y)\;dy$ and  $g''(x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: @Ramiro Guerreiro, thank you. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Sorry but how did you get the $f(x)x$ and $-xf(x)$ in the first derivative?

Comment: Can someone explain the first derivative? Exactly which formula is used?

Comment: @Isy product rule for x (integral). first d/dx of x, then d/dx of (integral)

Answer (score 5):

Write $g(x) = -x\displaystyle \int_{0}^x f(y)dy+\displaystyle \int_{0}^x yf(y)dy\to g'(x) =-\displaystyle \int_{0}^x f(y)dy-xf(x)+xf(x)=-\displaystyle \int_{0}^x f(y)dy\to g''(x) = - f(x)\to g'''(x) = -f'(x)$ From this we see that $n = 1$